# is it possible / plausible to read through a html page and add extra elements at certain points with php?

Tags: php, html

Lets say for example i have a very standard html page as such:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="add-container-element">
            This is Test Text
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to wrap elements with certain classes in container elements, ie:

```
<div class="container" />
```

i've been pointed towards php dom manipulation, however i'm not all that familiar with php and would be great if i could have an example of how it could be done?

The general idea is that i will be able to do essentially what i would do with javascript for users that have no javascript enabled.

Many thanks

-Jai

Comment: Id look into using XSL Transformations, would be much simpler to be honest.

Comment: This looks very much like an XY problem - why would you want to manipulate ready-to-render html?

Comment: To clarify: You have a plain HTML file on your server, and you want to serve it, but only after manipulating it with PHP? Is there any reason you can't just convert it to `.php`?

Comment: what do you mean by an XY problem?

Comment: Possible? Absolutely. Look at any of the [DOM/XML/HTML manipulation extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php). Will it have an impact on load time? Sure it will. You'll need to test whether it's *too* slow or not.

Comment: @Jai http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341 happens quite often.

Comment: the file on the server would be generated in pure html, but if it forfills certain criteria then it will need have wrapping elements paced on some elements and i'd rather not use any javascript so was wondering if it could be done before the page is loaded

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are ways, but really, it'd be a lot more time consuming and complex than doing it manually. See, the main problem you have here, is you're not wrapping a div around the class="" , which would be easy - but you've got to find the class="", then find out what that's inside (for example; a ul), then find the closing tag for that ul - while ignoring any other ul tags that may open or close inside of this.

If you're just looking to  to get the element in a block, you could just add;

```
.add-container-element {
display: block; }
```

But er, that would be extremely hit and miss as to your intended results.

You could look at some DOM manipulation which may be easier, but this is a rare case where I think manually trawling through your code may be more time-efficient.

Comment: its not to do with css, I just need to be able to create wrapping elements, but reading through the files seems awfully awkward to me and i would have thought an open source language would definitely have alternatives!

Comment: Well, as I said, there are ways of doing it (albiet none time-efficient) - but on the open source language having alternatives front.. if I wanted to correct my php and add something in, I'd open the php file and correct it.. I wouldn't go looking for a solution in python to edit and serve my php pages.